# Accessing Self Created Package

Tags: java, package

I am new to using Java,

I have created a Package ,I wanted my other classes to access the constructor and methods in that package

For Example:

Binary_Tree.java

```
     Package binary_tree;//Creating my own package
     class Binary_Tree
        {
        Binary_Tree()
        {

        }
        public int height()
        {
        }
        }
```

I wanted a file named Heap.java file,which imports binary_tree package,
to access the Constructor and methods present in

```
import binary_tree.Binary_Tree;//importing the Package

    Class Heap
    {
    //Access the Binary_Tree.Constructor and Method files
    }
```

Comment: Java doesn't have `friend` classes. Package level permission **restricts** access to *other* classes within the same package.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch when importing predefined packages ,we can pass paramters to that package and use it,Likewise when we create a Userdefined package and pass parameters to it,Whether its not possible ??

Comment: When your constructor begins `Binary_Tree()` (without `private`, `public` or `protected`) **then** it has *package* level permission. **Meaning**, ***only** classes* in the same *package* can access it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch if the classes which are importing are not able to access that methods and Constructor ,then what is the need for User defined Packages ?

Comment: Packages form a hierarchical class name space, and you **can** make the constructor *more* permissive. If it began `public Binary_Tree()` then any other class could invoke it, if it began `protected Binary_Tree()` then any subclass could invoke it.